# Something like .= in PHP but adds data "Before" instead of "After"?

Tags: php

The code below adds `lo` **after** `Hel`, thus outputs `Hello` :

```
$foo = "Hel";
$bar = "lo";
$foo .= $bar;

echo $foo;
```

If I want to output `loHel` instead, without using `echo $bar . $foo` what would you guys do? Just curious if there's simpler way.

Comment: the simplest you're going to get is `$foo = $bar . $foo;`. I'm sure you could come up with another way of doing it, but nothing that'll be as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no equivalent** of the inverse of `.=` (such as `=.`).

You therefore will have to do it the long hand way.

`$foo .= $bar` is the same as `$foo = $foo . $bar;`

so you would have to do

```
$foo = $bar . $foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$bar .= $foo
echo $bar;
```

Alternatively you can use `substr_replace` to insert one string at the beginning of another as:

```
$foo = substr_replace($foo,$bar,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a shorthand way of doing this.

[String operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) in the PHP manual

Answer (score 0):

```
    $bar = "lo".$foo;
    $foo=$bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$bar .= $foo;
echo $bar; // Will output loHel
```

Answer (score 0):

`$foo .= $bar` is just a short form for `$foo = $foo . $bar`.

Unfortunately there is nothing like a *prepend operator* in PHP. So you can't avoid using `$foo = $bar . $foo`.